# Scratch ORG versioning with GitHub

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, versioning, dev-hub

Our company wants to use the benefits of SDFX's scrath orgs for versioning and deploying to our GIT repository.

Once we install the CLI I can see I need to login using the command `sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername`

Is this logging in part just for authentication and to count the number of scratch orgs one is using?

I am confused - is the scratch org generated from the ORG or from 'source' like described in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answers are "no" and "technically, neither" respectively.

### The point of authenticating

The Salesforce CLI tool, when first installed, has no connection to Salesforce whatsoever. You can use *some* of the functionality of the CLI in this state (you can create a project, make a new apex class, maybe a few other things), but most of the functionality requires the CLI to have a target org to perform the action against.

When you use the CLI to perform an action, that action is originating from your local computer, not Salesforce. To be able to have something outside of your target org perform actions within the target org, you need to authenticate.

When you use `sfdx force:auth:web:login`, you are going through one of the OAuth flows to give the CLI permission to make requests to that org on your behalf. This allows you to do things like query records using `sfdx force:data:soql:query`, retrieve/deploy metadata to a non-scratch org using `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` and `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`.

From there, the CLI handles setting up the appropriate requests, and using the appropriate (and for the most part, already existing) APIs.

### On configuration of scratch orgs

Technically, scratch orgs are not generated from an org, nor from source.

Creating a scratch org requires a dev hub org (and for the CLI to be authorized to make requests to that org), but the scratch org itself is not generated from any data or configuration in the dev hub org.

Salesforce themselves aren't likely to explain *why* a dev hub is required, but I think that reasonable speculation would be that it's part of preventing *everyone* in a given company from being able to use features that they haven't paid for (at least, not without a significant maintenance effort).

When you create a new SFDX project, you get a configuration file (/config/project-scratch-def.json) which allows you to control the "shape" of the scratch org (i.e. what features are enabled, a limited selection of Salesforce editions, and more). This file is what actually controls the configuration of your scratch orgs.

This configuration file is technically part of the "source" for your project (it can be managed by your code versioning system), but at the same time it's separate from the "source" of your org...the things like Apex classes, SObject definitions, Lightning components, Validation rules, etc... that actually reside within your org.

When I hear "source", I think of the things that can be moved around to different orgs *and* your local computer using commands like `sfdx force:source:push`, `sfdx force:source:pull`, `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve`, and `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`

### Conclusion

At time of writing, your dev hub org, your metadata/source, and the configuration file in your sfdx project all play their own roles in creating a scratch org. They are all necessary (well, you don't *need* to push any metadata to a scratch org, but you wouldn't be able to do much practical development without pushing metadata).

I think the most accurate answer to your question as worded is that the scratch org is generated from the CLI on your local machine using the scratch org configuration file in your project, and running the `sfdfx force:org:create` command requires authentication to a dev hub org for **[reasons not disclosed by Salesforce]**

Comment: Fantastic answer @derek - really cleared a few grey areas!

Answer (score 1):

Scratch Orgs are generated from source. Login to a DevHub is just to check you have the rights to create Scratch Orgs, and to count the number ofthem already created, compared to your allocated number.

Except this (checking if you have the rights to create a Scratch Org), all the Scratch Org content is coming from your source.